# Error installing python-snappy: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, gcc

I am using amazon ec2 ubuntu 11.04 server

```
 sudo pip install python-snappy
```

also I tried to downloaded package and entered "sudo python setup.py install"

I got the error:

```
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'snappy' extension
  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c snappymodule.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappymodule.o
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
  snappymodule.cc:31:22: fatal error: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How i could get rid of this error?

source: https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy

Comment: install [snappy](http://code.google.com/p/snappy/) C library.

Comment: Can you share how do you install snappy C library? Add that to the path before python install or sth else. Thanks

Comment: URL changed for snappy C: http://google.github.io/snappy/

Comment: What about on windows?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need Snappy C [library](http://google.github.io/snappy/)

Then you have to install python-snappy wrapper.

It seems you didn't install Snappy-C library

Try it ..as already a fellow commented for your post

> UPDATE: See more highly upvoted post below, which includes instructions to install on DEB-based, RPM-based, and Mac OS (Brew).

Comment: on RPM-based execute: `wget url_to_download_snappy; tar xf snappy-x.y.z.tar.gz; cd snappy-x.y.z; ./configure; make install; pip install python-snappy`

Comment: Snappy library has moved to github, thus it won't work anymore

Comment: For Debian based system, following should work : sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev

Comment: sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev -> worked got ubuntu!

Answer (score 144):

You can install Snappy C library with following commands:

**DEB-based:** `sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev`

**RPM-based:** `sudo yum install csnappy-devel`

**Alpine (Docker)** `apk add --no-cache snappy-dev g++`

**openSUSE:** `sudo zypper in snappy-devel`

**MacOS:** See [Riley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41707800/1632891) below.

Comment: if on a mac and brew is installed, then `brew install snappy` also works.

Comment: I think it is `sudo yum install snappy-devel`

Comment: Its (tried on centos7)  `yum install csnappy-devel`

Comment: Thanks `sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev` worked for me, I am using ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.6.9

Comment: For alpine linux (for docker) `apk add --no-cache snappy-dev g++` solved the problem

Answer (score 60):

According to the [repo](https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy)

**How to install it on Mac OS X?**

It has been reported a few times (Issue #7 and #23) that it can't be installed correctly the library in Mac. 
The procedure should be,

```
$ brew install snappy # snappy library from Google 
$ CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib" pip install python-snappy
```

Comment: The `CPPFLAGS` part was essential. This is missing from every other answer, and very hidden in the `python-snappy` docs.

Comment: `CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib"` for Apple Silicon

Comment: Just an FYI - appending the CPPFLAGS to `poetry install` didn't work but going into shell and doing `pip install` with the prepended Env works.

Comment: @David for poetry install, i had to export, not just appending

Answer (score 3):

I had some trouble getting snappy to install. Finally downloaded the pre-build stuff as offered by https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and all went well.
(Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages)

Answer (score 3):

for Oracle Linux with Python 3.X:

you need to enable optional_latest repository as a first step,

1. use for enabling the following repo

   `$ yum-config-manager --enable ol7_optional_latest`

   "ol7_optional_latest" repo will be enabled for yum lookup.
2. then install packages using,

   `$ yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ snappy snappy-devel`
3. then with pip install the python-snappy package,

   `$ pip3 install python-snappy`

Comment: can you also try with RHEL8, if possible. I am facing such issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962861/snappy-c-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2):

1. You download snappy lib at here: https://code.google.com/p/snappy/
2. Extract it
3. Install by command lines follows:
   $: ./configure
   $: make
   $: make install
4. Install python-snappy: 
   $: pip install python-snappy

Answer (score 2):

had lots of issues installing on El Capitan, with an error saying that the snappy-c.h file was not found.

Had to install snappy from tar.gz file 
https://github.com/google/snappy/releases/download/1.1.3/snappy-1.1.3.tar.gz

untar and run

```
./configure
make
make install
```

it will put the header file in 
`/usr/local/include`

then needed to set FLAGS for the cc compiler to find the header file:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/include
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/snappy-c.h"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/snappy-c.h"
export CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/snappy-c.h"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
```

and then I installed python-snappy from the egg file
https://pypi.python.org/packages/b1/fe/1d632cdac5dbb5ce84db778af7f733eb469130d8cf4c02f6cd9057a96768/snappy-2.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-intel.egg#md5=b76558c71f1d97feeb8402c345e466bf

you can try with `pip install python-snappy`
but it originally failed to find the header file, so i went for the egg file

to install the egg:

```
easy_install <eggfile>
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the output for

```
rpm -q snappy-devel
```

If it is not present, then install it using this command:

```
yum install snappy-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on **Mac OS X Catalina**, you can install with

```
brew install snappy
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -stdlib=libc++ " pip install python-snappy
```

as suggested by https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy FAQ

Answer (score 2):

Fix for macOS M1. You have to define absolute path to lib and include for snappy.

```
brew install snappy
pip install \                               
  --upgrade --ignore-installed \
  python-snappy==0.5.4 \
  --global-option=build_ext \
  --global-option="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/snappy/1.1.9/include" \
  --global-option="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/snappy/1.1.9/lib"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue:

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having troubles with this for a while. FYI I'm trying to install Crossbar (https://crossbar.io/docs/Installation-on-Linux/)

I did a bunch of googling and messed around quite a bit. I'm using Python 3.7.4 and what I think solved my problem is this :

`sudo yum install python-devel`

if that doesn't work try

`sudo yum install python3-devel`

source:

https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1143#issuecomment-475354786

https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1143

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue in **Mac OS X with MacPorts** installed, you can do:

```
$ sudo port install snappy
$ CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib" pip install python-snappy
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows

1. Download from [here](https://cdn.machinezoo.com/download/snappy/snappy-windows-1.1.1.8.7z)

2. Extract the Zip.
3. Copy the `.h` files from include folder. Paste in to the python installation folder
   `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\`
4. Copy `snappy64.lib` from native folder. Paste in to python installation folder
   `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs\`
5. Rename `snappy64.lib` to `snappy.lib`
6. you are good to go. Re-try command `pip install -r .\requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install snappy
```

is ok for me

Answer (score 0):

**Mac OS - Apple Silicon**

If you have Apple Silicon, home-brew installs to /opt/homebrew by default.

So, the command changes to:

```
$ brew install snappy
$ CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib" pip install python-snappy
```

For Intel Silicon, you need the path to be */usr/local/include* & */usr/local/lib* as suggested above.

**FYI**: By -I & -L, we ask pip to look for include and library files in the homebrew directory resp. (where snappy and other brew packages would be located).