# Error when installing python-snappy in PyCharm

Tags: python, pyspark, pip, pycharm, parquet

I have a '.snappy.parquet' file and I wanted to view the content in this file, I know I can use pandas and PySpark.

[image]

This is beyond my knowledge, I'm not sure what to do, can someone help me please... I've been struggling for almost a day now.... Many thanks.
(and if I can't fix this issue, do I have other options to convert this file to a readable file?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install snappy C libraries on Windows 10 for use with python-snappy in Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979544/how-to-install-snappy-c-libraries-on-windows-10-for-use-with-python-snappy-in-an)

Comment: @Frodon Hi thanks for the link, I tried the first answer, but I got error `Hi I tried this, but got error ERROR: python_snappy-0.5.4-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 20.3 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.` Did I miss anything?

Comment: Did you try to upgrade pip as mentioned ?

Comment: Hi I've managed to install it `Installing collected packages: python-snappy Successfully installed python-snappy-0.5.4` but when I execute the script in PyCharm, seems like it's still giving the same error `RuntimeError: Decompression 'SNAPPY' not available.  Options: ['GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED']`

Comment: (In PyCharm, it still indicates `python-snappy` is not installed) Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved by using the approach here: [Can't install python-snappy wheel in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109444/cant-install-python-snappy-wheel-in-pycharm)

Answer (score -2):

You need snappy library written in C installed.
Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev
pip3 install python-snappy
```

Comment: I'm using a virtual env created in Pycharm, should I run those two lines in a windows prompt? and which directory should I use?