# Decompression 'SNAPPY' not available with fastparquet

Tags: python-3.x, snappy, fastparquet

I am trying to use fastparquet to open a file, but I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Decompression 'SNAPPY' not available.  Options: ['GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED']
```

I have the following installed and have rebooted my interpreter:

```
python                    3.6.5                hc3d631a_2  
python-snappy             0.5.2                    py36_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3  
fastparquet               0.1.5                    py36_0    conda-forge
```

Everything downloaded smoothly. I didn't know if I needed snappy or python-snappy so I got one had no fix and got the other, still with no success. All related issues I have found are fixed when downloading snappy, but I am still getting this error with having two snappys! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I ended up using pyspark to read my files because I never got a response. I am unsure how to fix this, but my project has since moved forward.

Comment: Didn't work for me either, even with pyspark installed as suggested by @Catbuilts. I circumvented the issue by using GZIP compression to save the Parquet file, then switching to pyarrow engine as that was far faster.

Comment: ```conda install -c conda-forge python-snappy fastparquet snappy``` worked for me. Installing those from conda base channel did not work somehow.

Comment: Hi just wondering how did you setup pyspark and get the result for this problem? I got the same error when using pandas.

Answer (score 29):

Run:

```
pip install python-snappy
pip install pyarrow
```

It should do the trick.

I think you lack the `pyarrow` package.

If you have an error with `pip`, use `conda` instead (i.e., `conda install python-snappy` or if you still have errors `conda install -c conda-forge python-snappy`).

Comment: Installing pyarrow is irrelevant. ```conda install -c conda-forge python-snappy fastparquet snappy``` worked for me. Installing those from base channel did not work somehow.

Comment: ^ **this** is the solution here; you need both python-snappy (the wrapper) and snappy (the C lib) from the same channel

Answer (score 13):

You need to install `python-snappy` as stated by the response of [Catbuilts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334453). However, it is only a wrapper around the [snappy implementation](http://google.github.io/snappy/) in c that should be installed in your computer, this issue has been addressed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20678150) about installing snappy-c.

Assuming you have a **DEB-based** system, such as ubuntu, you can get it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev
python3 -m pip install --user python-snappy
```

To test it, you can try the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import snappy  # Not required but snappy (python-snappy) module should be reachable
from fastparquet import write, ParquetFile
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3,4], "col2": ["a","b","c","d"]})
# df.head() # Test your initial value
write("/tmp/deleteme", df, compression="SNAPPY")
df_parquet = ParquetFile("/tmp/deleteme").to_pandas()
df_parquet.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following installations are pretty helpful

```sh
pip install fastparquet

pip install python-snappy

pip install pyarrow
```