# Python Pandas to convert CSV to Parquet using Fastparquet

Tags: python, pandas, fastparquet

I am using Python 3.6 interpreter in my PyCharm venv, and trying to convert a CSV to Parquet.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv('/parquet/drivers.csv')
df.to_parquet('output.parquet')
```

**Error-1**
    ImportError: Unable to find a usable engine; tried using: 'pyarrow', 'fastparquet'.
    pyarrow or fastparquet is required for parquet support

**Solution-1**
Installed fastparquet 0.2.1

**Error-2**
  File "/Users/python parquet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastparquet/compression.py", line 131, in compress_data
    (algorithm, sorted(compressions)))
RuntimeError: Compression 'snappy' not available.  Options: ['GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED']

I Installed **python-snappy 0.5.3** but still getting the same error? Do I need to install any other library?

If I use **PyArrow 0.12.0** engine, I don't experience the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In fastparquet snappy compression is an **optional** feature.

To quickly check a conversion from csv to parquet, you can execute the following script (only requires pandas and fastparquet):

```
import pandas as pd
from fastparquet import write, ParquetFile
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3,4], "col2": ["a","b","c","d"]})
# df.head() # Test your initial value
df.to_csv("/tmp/test_csv", index=False)
df_csv = pd.read_csv("/tmp/test_csv")
df_csv.head() # Test your intermediate value
df_csv.to_parquet("/tmp/test_parquet", compression="GZIP")
df_parquet = ParquetFile("/tmp/test_parquet").to_pandas()
df_parquet.head() # Test your final value
```

However, if you need to write or read using snappy compression you might follow this [answer about installing snappy library on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59789624/4311160).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following versions:
`python 3.10.9 fastparquet==2022.12.0 pandas==1.5.2`

This code works seemlessly for me

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/parquet/drivers.csv')
df.to_parquet('output.parquet', engine="fastparquet")
```

I'd recommend you move away from `python 3.6` as it has reached end of life and is no longer supported.