# How to read multiple .parquet files from multiple directories into single pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, parquet

I need to read parquet files from multiple directories.

for example,

```
 Dir---
          |
           ----dir1---
                      |
                       .parquet
                       .parquet
          |
           ----dir2---
                      |
                       .parquet
                       .parquet
                       .parquet
```

Is there a way to read these file to single pandas data frame?

note:
All of parquet files was generated using pyspark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`read_parquet`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) in list comprehension and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with all files generated by [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) with `**` (python 3.5+):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob('Dir/**/*.parquet')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_parquet(fp) for fp in files])
```

Comment: I got this error ```RuntimeError: Decompression 'SNAPPY' not available.  Options: ['GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED']```

Comment: @AhmadSuliman - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800748/decompression-snappy-not-available-with-fastparquet)

Comment: Will it work if each directly has over 30 parquet files of about 75MB each?