# Dask dataframe read parquet format fails from http

Tags: pandas, http, dask, parquet, fastparquet

I have been dealing with this problem for a week. 
I use the command

```
from dask import dataframe as ddf
ddf.read_parquet("http://IP:port/webhdfs/v1/user/...")
```

I got invalid parquet magic.
However ddf.read_parquet is Ok with "webhdfs://"

I would like the ddf.read_parquet works for http because I want to use it in dask-ssh cluster for workers without hdfs access.

Comment: First It is possible to use webhdfs in cluster. I was not correct about later. I tested webhdfs without hadoop.

Comment: I needed to add host name to /etc/hosts to server be known for python.

Comment: One library python-snappy was put down. It is addressed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800748/decompression-snappy-not-available-with-fastparquet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the comments already partly answer this question, I thought I would add some information as an answer

- HTTP(S) is supported by dask (actually `fsspec`) as a backend filesystem; but to get partitioning within a file, you need to get the size of that file, and to resolve globs, you need to be able to get a list of links, neither of which are necessarily provided by any given server
- webHDFS (or indeed httpFS) don't work like HTTP downloads, you need to use a specific API to open a file and fetch a final URL on a cluster member to that file; so the two methods are not interchangeable
- webHDFS is normally intended for use *outside* of the hadoop cluster; within the cluster, you would probably use plain HDFS (`"hdfs://"`). However, kerberos-secured webHDFS can be tricky to work with, depending on how the security was set up.

Comment: Wow! I am only a python user. I thought that it would be easy if I could study more about the HTTP server. Do multiple partitions of a file (part.0.parquet, part.1.parquet ,...) cause the problem if I understood? I don't know how different partitions within a part.0.parquet are  managed by a parquet engine like fastparquet. If I run.to_parquet(write_meta=False) for a large self-contained file part.0.parquet, still is it possible or not to read it from the HTTP server? thanks for the maintainers of fastparquet library  I found a missed requirements of pyarrow (lz4 ) in the project website.

Comment: Simply: the webHDFS just doesn't work in a way that you can use the HTTP file-system, it's more specialist, sorry.