# RuntimeError: Decompression 'SNAPPY' not available. Options: ['BROTLI', 'GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED'] (error happens only in .py and not in .ipython)

Tags: python, snappy, fastparquet

I got this error as in the title while trying to read parquet files using fastparquet with the following codes:

```
from fastparquet import ParquetFile
pf = ParquetFile(myfile.parquet)
df = pf.to_pandas()
```

I tried the solutions suggested from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800748/decompression-snappy-not-available-with-fastparquet), but they did not work for me.

Afterwards, I also tried the following: 
I uninstalled `snappy` from all my environments (as default `python-snappy` was also uninstalled together by conda).
Then I installed `python-snappy` only in one environment - let's say `env1` (as default `snappy` was installed together by conda). And I ran the same codes in `.py` and `.ipython` both in `env1`. Again `.py` did not work (same error as above) and `.ipython` worked...  
Then I ran them in another environment (`env2`, where I did not installed `python-snappy` yet), and `.ipython` **worked again**!! And in this environment, `.py` did not work, which I can understand, since I did not install it yet. I am really confused what happened there and why `.py` won't work properly. I would appreciate any hints.

Details about packages and versions please see [here](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/563)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around, I found a workaround:
I downloaded the wheel file of python-snappy from [the PyPI website](https://pypi.org/project/python-snappy/#files) and manually installed it via `pip install --force-reinstall python_snappy-0.6.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` and this error disappeared.
Hopefully, this can help others having the same issue.