# Google Cloud Composer, cannot install python-snappy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to install `python-snappy` in Google Cloud Composer through Google Cloud Platform console. I am using python3 environment.

I had tried to install different `python-snappy` versions (0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5, 0.4), however, it always raises this error:

> Http error status code: 400 Http error message: BAD REQUEST Additional
>   errors:
>   {"ResourceType":"w071b50175ee0733c-tp/asia-northeast1-kumparan-co-e2ca75b3-gae-typer:appengine.apps.services.versions.create","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"Docker
>   image gcr.io/w071b50175ee0733c-tp/c949bad3-ca30-4717-a975-8e36bae3929a
>   was either not found, or is not in Docker V2 format. Please visit
>   https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/ui "}

I also had tried to rerun, as discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-composer-discuss/jpxAGCPFkZo.

But, it doesn't solve this issue in my case.

Any body knows how to solve it?

Comment: Can you include the exact install command you used?

Comment: as I said, I am using GCP console to install the library. So, it is done just by inserting the library name. You can take a look at this link, see `Installing a Python dependency from PyPi` part in tab `console`.
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/, you should see a failed build with the following logs:

```
Failed building wheel for python-snappy
Running setup.py clean for python-snappy
Failed to build python-snappy
Installing collected packages: python-snappy
Running setup.py install for python-snappy: started
Running setup.py install for python-snappy: finished with status 'error'
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-M5s4qk/python-snappy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-EuqCf8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy
copying snappy/snappy_cffi_builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy
copying snappy/snappy_cffi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy
copying snappy/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy
copying snappy/snappy_formats.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy
copying snappy/snappy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy
copying snappy/hadoop_snappy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy
copying snappy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy
running build_ext
building 'snappy._snappy' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c snappy/snappymodule.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappy/snappymodule.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
snappy/snappymodule.cc:31:22: fatal error: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory
#include <snappy-c.h>
^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

This is because the `python-snappy` package is only the Python bindings to the underlying C library, not the C library itself.

See ["Error installing python-snappy: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416024/error-installing-python-snappy-snappy-c-h-no-such-file-or-directory) for more details.

Comment: yes, you're right. the problem here is we cannot install C library in Google Cloud Composer, because C library is a system-level package. Google Cloud Composer doesn't support installing arbitrary system packages, as discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-composer-discuss/jpxAGCPFkZo