# MacOS pip install numbers-parser fails building snappy, but python snappy already installed

Tags: python, macos, snappy

Trying to install numbers-parser…

```
python3.11 -m pip install numbers-parser      # → fails with below error...
```

Fails with **ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-snappy** because `/usr/bin/clang` can't find `snappy-c.h`

However, python-snappy is already installed…

```
python3.11 -m snappy -h      # → prints the help message
```

I've tried a variety of things listed [in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11416024/740987) but no success. I'm puzzled it still wants to build python-snappy when it's already installed and functional.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: `python3 -m pip install python-snappy` Released: Mar 14, 2024

Comment: @toyotaSupra thanks but same result as above, as python3 links to python3.11